Hide Auxiliary Mouse pointer (from secondary monitor) on linux
We have a dual monitor setup connected to a linux machine. We have created an auxiliary mouse pointer for the second monitor using the xserver . Command to create the auxiliary pointer : xinput create-master Auxiliary.
Our requirement is that the touch functionality should work, but the cursor should be invisible (only for the auxiliary mouse pointer).
So far all the solutions we have seen work only for the primary mouse pointer, is there a way to specifically target the auxiliary mouse pointer and make it invisible?
Here is what the xinput response looks like :
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Lenovo USB Optical Mouse           id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Melfas LGD AIT Touch Controller           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Datalogic ADC, Inc. Powerscan PD9500      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ LITE-ON Technology USB NetVista Full Width Keyboard.  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
⎡ Auxiliary pointer                         id=16   [master pointer  (17)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=14   [slave  pointer  (16)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=15   [slave  pointer  (16)]
⎜   ↳ Auxiliary XTEST pointer                   id=18   [slave  pointer  (16)]
⎣ Auxiliary keyboard                        id=17   [master keyboard (16)]
    ↳ Auxiliary XTEST keyboard                  id=19   [slave  keyboard (17)]


